# No tools attribute for fresco components, like SimpleDraweeView

Tags: android, android-studio, fresco

I am using Fresco 1.13.0 in my project. I want to see how a `SimpleDraweeView` renders an image in layout editor by using its tools attribute. But it seems that tools attribute is not working with `SimpleDraweeView`. All I want to do is use sample data provided in Android Studio's latest release.

The `SimpleDraweeView` is to be used inside a `RecyclerView` for showing some image from server. And I can set `tools:listItem` in RecyclerView to view its items in layout editor itself without need to install app on an emulator or real device to test the UI. But I cannot set the same tools attribute to a `SimpleDraweeView`, it doesn't recognize this.

This is my code for using `SimpleDraweeView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/drawee_product_desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:placeholderImage="@tools:sample/avatar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the rendered layout

[image: Snapshot of Empty SImpleDraweeView shown]

So is there any way I can use `tools` attribute to set a sample image into `SimpleDraweeView`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
    android:id="@+id/drawee_product_desc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/your_place_holder"
    app:placeholderImage="@drawable/your_place_holder"
    fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want to set a sample data using ```@tools:sample/```.  Not a custom drawable resource.  ```@tools:sample/``` works perfectly in an ```ImageView``` but not in a ```SimpleDraweeView```

Comment: All I had to do was create a json file and inside its json key's value, I had to put reference to the drawable resources which I want to use as sample data, and then inside `fresco:placeHolderImage`, I had to put reference to that specific key inside the json file which contains reference to drawable resource.